# How to insert a list of objects using stored proc in ado.net

Tags: stored-procedures, ado.net

Let's say I have this method

```
public static void LockPerformanceToDB(List<performance> listOfPerformances)
{
    //Do I need just to wrap this call with a loop? ... 
    using(var con = new OpenConnection)
    {
       //I call the LockPerformanceToDB SPROC here ...
    }
}
```

I also have this procedure in the database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LockPerformancesToDB
    @UserId INT,
    @Comments VARCHAR(50),
    @TimeStamp DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Performance
    (UserId, Comments, [TimeStamp])
    VALUES
    (@UserId, @Comments, @TimeStamp)
END
```

This sproc handles one insertion at time. As it's obvious that the list has several of the same performance objects. Is looping through each object of the list the solution?

I'd like to know whether there is a different solution besides looping and calling the sproc as many times as there are objects in the lisOfPerformances?

Thanks for helping

Comment: You will need connection and command objects to do this.  [Here](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet) is a tutorial to get you started.

Comment: My question is not on how to write a store procedure, but on how to write an ADo.NET code that handles a list. So far, what I have been doing is to wrap the call to the sproc with a foreach loop. I call the sproc for the first object, then for the second and so forth. Now I don't know whether there is another way to do that.

Comment: I understand your ask now, it initially sounded like you didn't know _how_ to write the ADO.NET code to do it.  That being said, I think you should post the ADO.NET code you have at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Table-Valued Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) to pass multiple rows to the stored procedure.

> Table-valued parameters are declared by using user-defined table types. You can use table-valued parameters to send multiple rows of data to a Transact-SQL statement or a routine, such as a stored procedure or function, without creating a temporary table or many parameters.

1. Create the type

   ```
   Create Type TVP_LockPerformancesToDB As Table(
    UserId int, Comments varchar(50), [TimeStamp] datetime)
   ```
2. Create the stored procedure as

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE LockPerformancesToDB2
   @CommentInfo TVP_LockPerformancesToDB READONLY
   AS
   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Performance
      (UserId, Comments, [TimeStamp])
       SELECT UserId, Comments, [TimeStamp]
     FROM @CommentInfo
   END
   ```
3. Then in your code

   ```
   class Performance
   {
       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public string Comments { get; set; }
       public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
   }



   List<Performance> listOfPerformances = new List<Performance>() {
        new Performance{ UserId=1, Comments="First", TimeStamp=DateTime.Now},
        new Performance{ UserId=2, Comments="Second", TimeStamp=DateTime.Now},
        new Performance{ UserId=3, Comments="Third", TimeStamp=DateTime.Now}
    };


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("UserId", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("Comments", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("TimeStamp", typeof(DateTime));
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfPerformances.Count; i++)
    {
       dt.Rows.Add(listOfPerformances[i].UserId, listOfPerformances[i].Comments, listOfPerformances[i].TimeStamp);
    }

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "LockPerformancesToDB2";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("CommentInfo", SqlDbType.Structured));
    cmd.Parameters["CommentInfo"].Value = dt;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   ```